# How to parse a JSON with comments inside?

Tags: json, go

In `go` the standard package [encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) exposes `json.Unmarshal` function to parse JSON.

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    ...
    "tyo": {
        "ping_only": true,
        "addresses": [
            //"155.133.245.25:27015-27050",
            //"155.133.245.26:27015-27050",
            //"155.133.245.27:27015-27050",
            "45.121.186.20:27015-27016",
            "45.121.186.21:27015-27016"
        ]
    },
    "vie": {
        "addresses": [
            "185.25.182.225:27015-27050",
            "185.25.182.226:27015-27050"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

When I use `json.Unmarshal` I got error:

> Handler crashed with error invalid character '/' looking for beginning of value

Can someone tell me how to parse this?

Comment: This is __invalid__ json. No comments are allowed in json.

Comment: check out this article https://golangexample.com/json-with-comments-for-go/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strict [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt), don't allow comments.

But exist not-official superset of JSON that permits comments (and more other cool things), like [**JSON5**](http://json5.org/) or [**HJSON**](https://hjson.org) (human-json).

You can try with these Go libraries:

- JSON5: https://github.com/yosuke-furukawa/json5
- HJSON: https://github.com/client9/xson/tree/master/hjson

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple json uncommenter in go that support line comment.
use it before unmarshal.

```golang
    // f is a raw io.Reader
    newReader := jsonuncommenter.RemoveComment(f)

    jsonParser := json.NewDecoder(newReader)
    var s seeds
    jsonParser.Decode(&s)
```

https://github.com/wuxiangzhou2010/jsonuncommenter

Answer (score 0):

Yes,this is invalid JSON.

I found a solution:

```
for _, v:= range s {
    if len(strings.TrimSpace(v)) > 3 {
        if strings.TrimSpace(v)[:1] != "/" {
            t = t + v
        }
    } else {
        t = t + v
    }
}
```